# What is the meaning of the tall clouds in "The Girl who leapt through time"?

Tags: analysis, the-girl-who-leapt-through-time

I noticed a motif of really tall clouds in "[The girl who leapt through time](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0808506/?ref_=ttexrv_exrv_tt)" (時をかける少女, 2006).

I think the cloud is either a [cumulonimbus calvus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulonimbus_calvus) or a [cumulus congestus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulus_congestus_cloud). I read the latter breaks apart fairly quickly, which could make that cloud a motif for transience.

The fair amount of screen time and repetition of the cloud made me wondering why is it used so often? Is it used as a zeitgeber? Is there some philosophical or cultural meaning? So, what is the (intended) function of depicting those specific clouds?

---

```
15:20 First time leap.
```

[image: First time leap]

---

```
50:20 Kaho talking about how much her         1:24:20 Makato running to Chiaki.
      sick grandmother likes Kousuke
```

[image: Kaho talk]
[image: The girl who leapt through time 1:24:20]

By the way are those skulls? Is it an element of transcience, as Makato is hurrying to talk with Chiaki?

---

```
1:32:50 End shot                              1:37:10 Title screen.
```

[image: The girl who leapt through time 1:32:20]
[image: Girl who leapt through time 1:37:10]

Answer (score -1):

There's a glimpse of answer in Japanese cinematic tendencies called pillow shots, cultural backgrounds at Japan, emotional stimulus at clouds and cultural discourse of clouds animation in another journal. I'm currently having a thesis research for seeking meanings in animation focusing on background art specifically on cumulus congestus clouds and blue sky. I will gladly share my research result here since I have questions in the same film and another films with same tendencies.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion about *pillow shots*. If you care to elaborate your answer I would be delighted. Also I recently noticed these *cumulus congestus* in a Japanese live-action drama. Perhaps the clouds that common that the Japanese audience can relate to them? And if so, in what way?